# How to save SO favorites to Evernote?

Tags: discussion

I apologize in advance if this is not the correct place to ask this question (please kindly inform me if this is the case) but I'm wondering what the easiest way to save SO favorites to Evernote would be (both old ones and new ones). So there are really two questions here:

(1) How do I most easily save all existing SO favorites to Evernote? (this is perhaps the trickier of the two)

(2) Is there a clean way to automatically save new SO favorites to Evernote (IFTTT style), or would it be easiest to simple favorite the item AND webclip it each time (not ideal but one potential solution that comes to mind).

Would love to hear your input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get an RSS feed of your favorites this way: http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/users/22656/favorites?body=true

Knowing that, I made 2 new IFTTT recipies.

The first uses your favorites to add to Delicious: https://ifttt.com/recipes/62535

The second does evernote: https://ifttt.com/recipes/62544

Note that 22656 is Jon Skeet's number.  Use your own :)